# Visual Studio 2010-like multiple-monitor support for Windows Forms applications?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio-2010, multiple-monitors

I have the following project.

The main form has control in it. This control displays something (scanned images for example). I have two monitors. So I need to be able to drag that control from the main window to the second monitor so I have main window AND control displaying something visible at the same time.

I know that such functionality does exists in Visual Studio 2010 where you can move your code files and other windows from main IDE window to the second monitor.

I want to implement the same kind of functionality for my windows application written in C#, Visual Studio 2010.

If you could recommend a library, sample code or third party component to achieve that I would highly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: Library?  Fire up two windows, use Screens to position them, and that's it...  or is it?

Comment: So are you wanting to use a tab interface or something like Vs ?

Comment: Something like VS would be prefereable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tear off tab functionality like that of visual studio can be found in Avalon Dock:
http://avalondock.codeplex.com/

I do not have experience with the new 2.0 release but the old release was reasonably stable and did support winforms.

Comment: Thanks b_levitt, I appreciate your reply. Let me check it out! Anvar

Comment: OK, I have tried the Avalon. I have a unique scenario though. There is a windows user control, which I need to host inside of the WPF Avalon Docking control. It does not seem possible at this point. Did you try doing that in your development and was it possible for your project? I am giving you a point and answer point anyways. Thanks!

Comment: Just want to add that AvalonDock seems to be a good option for WPF projects. It is bit more finicky with regular winforms applications. Thanks again b_levitt for pointing on that components.

Comment: My personal experience with AvalonDock is with WPF.  However, the documentation states that the old 1.3 version did support hosting winforms controls.  Did you try the 1.3 version or the new 2.0 beta version?